# Find the number of previous consecutive occurences of value different than current row value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume that we have the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0,0,1,0,0,0,0],'y':[1,1,1,1,1,1,0],'z':[0,1,1,1,0,0,1]})

   x  y  z
0  0  1  0
1  0  1  1
2  1  1  1
3  0  1  1
4  0  1  0
5  0  1  0
6  0  0  1
```

All dataframe is filled either by 1 or 0. Looking at each column separately, if current row value is different than previous value I need to count number of previous consecutive values:

```
   x  y  z
0        
1        1
2  2     
3  1     
4        3
5        
6     6  2
```

I tried to write a lambda function and apply it to entire dataframe, but I failed. Any idea?

Comment: and what fills the rest of the data frame?

Comment: Output dataframe has missing values when current value is the same as previous. Consequently also the first row has missing values.

Comment: Why use 0 and 1 instead of actual boolean values?

Comment: In general problem can be extended to allow more than only 0 or 1 values in dataframe. I suppose limiting only to boolean can provide faster implementations, but I wanted not to narrow solution only to binary values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
def f(col):
    x = (col != col.shift().bfill())
    s = x.cumsum()
    return s.groupby(s).transform('count').shift().where(x)

df.apply(f).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
   x  y  z
0         
1        1
2  2      
3  1      
4        3
5         
6     6  2
```

***Details:***

Use `apply`, to apply a custom function on each column of the dataframe.
Find the difference spots in the column then use `cumsum` to create groups of consecutive values, then `groupby` and `transform` to create a `count` for each record, then mask the values in the column using `where` for the difference spots.

Comment: Great result and explanation. I'm curious if another solution exists based on applying function to rows instead to column: `df.apply(function, axis=1)`. Expected result is exactly the same.

Comment: Using apply(axis=1) is a pretty big "no no" in pandas.  With that statement you are iterating row by row it defeats the purpose of vectorizing your procedure.  You can most of times find a way not to go row by row.  Apply with axis=1 is one of the slowest things to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following, where you identify the "runs" first, get the "runs" lengths. You will only entry at where it switches, so it is the lengths of the runs except the last one.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def func(x,missing=np.NaN):
        runs = np.cumsum(np.append(0,np.diff(x)!=0))
        switches = np.where(np.diff(x!=0))[0] + 1
        out = np.repeat(missing,len(x))
        out[switches] = np.bincount(runs)[:-1]
        # thanks to Scott see comments below 
        ##out[switches] = pd.value_counts(runs,sort=False)[:-1]
        return(out)

df.apply(func)

    x   y   z
0   NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN 1.0
2   2.0 NaN NaN
3   1.0 NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN 3.0
5   NaN NaN NaN
6   NaN 6.0 2.0
```

It might be faster with a good implementation of run length encoding.. but I am not too familiar with it in python..

Comment: To get better performance, you can change out your `out[switches] = pd.value_counts(runs, sort=False)[:-1]` and use `out[switches] = np.bincount(runs)[:-1]`.

Comment: I was surprised Your solution is nearly 3 times faster than solution of ScottBoston which on the other side seems to be more compact.

Comment: @lpj Yes, using numpy for calculation is always faster than using pandas.  pandas uses a lot of numpy plus extra.  If you can write your logic using numpy only, then it will always run faster.  Hence, my suggestion above to change our pd.value_counts for np.bincount. I am much more familiar with pandas than numpy.   I learn from great numpy answers here.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the great suggestion. Yup in this case np.bincount works well, I will include that in the answer. Nice pandas code btw.

Comment: Howdy @StupidWolf. Your code is great. No problem.  Feel free to use that code.